# How to check the algorithm used in key generation using openssl genrsa output

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, public-key

- I have create a keypair using

  `openssl genrsa -out test1.key`
- I want to verify how the key is encrypted, by looking at `openssl genrsa --help`  ,
- -des            encrypt the generated key with DES in cbc mode
- -des3           encrypt the generated key with DES in ede cbc mode (168 bit key)
  --idea           encrypt the generated key with IDEA in cbc mode
- I used `openssl rsa -in test1.key -text` but it is not showing any information
  about those.

Please if there is anyway to check that?

Comment: There are no ciphers, it's a RSA key pair. What exactly are you expecting? Your second command shows you all the properties of the key, there's nothing else about it to show.

Comment: You did not specify a password, so it is not encrypted. If you did (eg: `-passout pass:foobar -aes128`), you would see it in the file itself: `... DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC`

Comment: Now i understood . Thanks @Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting an encrypted key, but it isn't by default. The [genrsa man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/genrsa.html) clearly states (emphasis mine):

> -aes128|-aes192|-aes256|-aria128|-aria192|-aria256|-camellia128|-camellia192|-camellia256|-des|-des3|-idea
>
> These options encrypt the private key with specified cipher before
> outputting it. **If none of these options is specified no encryption
> is used**. If encryption is used a pass phrase is prompted for if it
> is not supplied via the -passout argument.

This can also be seen from the generated PEM file which has no information other than the key itself:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out test-plain.key
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
...........................................................................................+++++
..........................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)

$ head -n 2 test-plain.key 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA5RCtTAg3fuspy1VdZpHqrFz4Lt9p5MnZkjH0FZ9wAk9vpvRF
```

On the other hand, if we specify an encryption algorithm to apply to the key, two things happen:

- I am prompted for a password (unless specified through `-passout`)
- the algorithm and block cipher mode is shown in the PEM output

```
$ openssl genrsa -out test-aes.key -aes128
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
............................................................+++++
................................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Enter pass phrase for test-aes.key: foobar
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for test-aes.key: foobar

$ head -n 3 test-aes.key 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,ED364325F65A0F212D07BC9E643D6424
```

We can clearly see that `AES-128-CBC` is being used with the indicated IV.